# Using preprocess in drupal form

Tags: drupal

i have prepared a drupal registration form with basic fields like name,email,etc. Then i created a display function where data is selected from database and displayed. Now my instructor asked me to somehow include preprocessor in my program.How do i do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, like what version of drupal are you using and how did you create webform, with back-end interface or from code and I guess you are going to get some down votes for your question, but I'll try to help anyway.

So, Drupal uses so called "hooks" system. You have some process, like web form creations and it's done from several steps. At some points (i.e. between those steps) you can interrupt the process, let you own code execute and then let process continue with normal flow.

Way to do that is by creating your own hooks functions. You have to make your module (some can work even from theme's template.php file), then create hook function inside module file, give it specific name, to meet some standards, clear the cash and Drupal will take care to call your hook function when appropriate event happens.

The hook you'll have to create most likely is:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

So if your module is called i.e."saikat" (it's machine name) you'll have to create function called:

```
    saikat_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id)
    {
      // Do your magic here
    }
```

This hook will be called for every form you have on your website so check on $form_id value to match your form id to alter only your form and no others as well. And don't forget to clear the cache.